# Mongodb aggregation lookup record limit

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have this function in my moongose+mongodb:

```
   Blog.aggregate([{
                "$match": {"user_id": userblog}},
                {
                "$lookup": {
                    from: "comments", // collection name in db
                    localField: "_id",
                    foreignField: "blogid",
                    as: "comments"
                },                  
            }]).exec(function(err, docs) {


            });
```

This works perfectly, but how could i do to limit the comments and retrive last 10 records? Thank's a lot. Marco.

Comment: You are looking for [`$slice`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/slice/). `$lookup` is returning an array, so that's the thing you are "limiting". There has to be a duplicate around somewhere, but search is failing me right now. Still there should be something here before one more peanut just blindly posts `$limit` without actually reading the question.

Answer (score 1):

add a limit to your code

```
Blog.aggregate([{
        "$match": {"user_id": userblog}},
        {
        "$lookup": {
            from: "comments", // collection name in db
            localField: "_id",
            foreignField: "blogid",
            as: "comments"
        }
    }]).limit(10).exec(function(err, docs) {

    });
```

Comment: place lean().exec(function(err, doc)) it will remove all getter and setters and give you plain document

Comment: **EDITED MY COMMENT SO PLEASE DO CHECK THAT**

Answer (score 1):

For anyone struggling on this here how you can limit a `$lookup` aggregation pipeline using mongoose. the `pipeline` operator allow you to execute query over your joined collection

```
Model
 .aggregate()
 .lookup({
   from: 'comments',
   localField: '_id',
   foreignField: 'commentId',
   as: 'comments',
   pipeline: [
     // ...pipeline operator here like $match...
     { $limit: 10 },
     { $sort: { createdAt: -1 } } // To order by most recent results
   ]
})
```

The `.lookup()` is a mongoose helpers for executing aggregation in order to use it natively

```
db.comments.aggregate([
 {
  $lookup: {
    from: 'comments',
    localField: '_id',
    foreignField: 'commentId',
    as: 'comments',
    pipeline: [
     // ...pipeline operator here like $match...
     { $limit: 10 },
     { $sort: { createdAt: -1 } } // To order by most recent results
    ]
  }
}
])
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add limit into aggregation:

```
Blog.aggregate([{
                "$match": {"user_id": userblog}},
                {
                "$lookup": {
                    from: "comments", // collection name in db
                    localField: "_id",
                    foreignField: "blogid",
                    as: "comments"
                }, 
                {
                    "$limit" : 10
                }                 
            }]).exec(function(err, docs) {


            });
```

Comment: Pretty sure that the question is asking "last 10 from the comments collection", since that actually is what the text in the question says.

Comment: Sorry..it's true! Last 10 from the comments collection!

Comment: Don't works in mongoose there is en error on  }, 
                {
                    "$limit" : 10
                }